# \include not working in SageMath LaTeX

Tags: input, include

I'm using SageMathCloud's LaTeX.

So I've got five `.tex` documents (all pretty long) with similar formatting. I want to add all five files into one large file that will respect the preambles of all five files.

I thought `\include` would be my best option. However, it is not working. By that I mean that I enter it and nothing happens, not even an Error. I've tried using `\input`, but this option does not respect preambles of the documents. Additionally, for some reason, the `\input` command won't work unless I use the `standalone` package.

I've been entering this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\includepdf{cover.pdf}
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents

\include{doc1.tex}
\include{doc2.tex}
\include{doc3.tex}
\include{doc4.tex}
\include{doc5.tex}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: your question is very hard to understand, what do you mean by " not respect preambles of the documents" ? whether you use `\input` or `\include` the format of the files being included is the same and must not have a preamble of its own but be tex code that would be allowed at that point in the main document.

Comment: @Nasser  I think you're right and I might be confused. Is there any way to combine all the five documents together under one main document and have the preambles (and by that I really mean the formatting and such things) remain intact for all five documents? That is just simply import the files as is under one large file. Perhaps only having things like the page number change.

Comment: This was nicely detailed article. But I'm getting an undefinted control sequence for \subimport

Comment: @Alondra I don't think there is a general way to combine different documents with different preambles into a single file (other than compiling each one and then including them as pdfs for example).  My answer below uses the same preamble (defined in `master.tex` for each document allowing you to treat them as independent documents, or as a combined document.)

Answer (score 1):

The recommended approach for multiple files with Sage MathCloud (SMC) is to use the `subfiles` package.  This allows you to use the same preamble for all files, but unlike `\include` or `\input` allows each subfile to be build on its own so you can edit them in a sensible manner online.

A [complete working example can be found here](https://github.com/sagemath/cloud-examples/tree/master/latex/multiple-files).

Your master file, which I call `master.tex` here, should look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subfiles}   % This is the recommended solution for multiple files on SMC

\title{Title of Document}
\author{Name of Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\subfile{doc1.tex}
\end{document}
%sagemathcloud={"latex_command":"latexmk -g -pdf master"}
```

(The comment at the end instructs Sage MathCloud how to build the master file - I am using `latexmk` here.)

Now your subfiles `doc1.tex` etc. should look like this:

```
\documentclass[master.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\section{File doc1}
\end{document}
%sagemathcloud={"latex_command":"latexmk -g -pdf doc1"}
```

When you edit this file on SMC, you should only get the file `doc1.tex` but typeset with the full preamble (so you can quickly edit only that section without recompiling everything for example).

Comment: I keep getting an issue warning that `\documentclass[master.tex]{subfiles}` is causing an emergency stop.  The subfiles either have a LaTex Error: missing \begin{document} or Missing Number,treated as zero

Comment: @Alondra If you save the two examples given above as `master.tex` and `doc1.tex`, then you should be able to compile the files on SMC (I just tried it).  If something does not work, you will have to post a more specific (not)working example.