# Impossible to run the command: sage "Sage-example".sagetex.sage (Windows 10)

Tags: texstudio, windows, sagetex

Good evening guys.

I've a big problem, as to simplify my school report, and don't do stupid mistakes while copy pasting some equations, I decided to try `SageTex`, and I've been struggling to make it works as an automated compilation.
To be fair, I had to reinstall all because of an hard drive problem (MiKTeX console and texstudio  3.0.1, plus SageMath9.1, of course), and followed this guide, step by step.
(post:[sagetex in texstudio : define a new build tool](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/541256/sagetex-in-texstudio-define-a-new-build-tool) )

This is my little experimental example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}

\begin{document}

Using Sage\TeX, one can use Sage to compute things and put them into
your \LaTeX{} document. For example, there are
$\sage{number_of_partitions(1269)}$ integer partitions of $1269$.
You don't need to compute the number yourself, or even cut and paste
it from somewhere.

Here's some Sage code:

\begin{sageblock}
    f(x) = exp(x) * sin(2*x)
\end{sageblock}

The second derivative of $f$ is

\[
  \frac{\mathrm{d}^{2}}{\mathrm{d}x^{2}} \sage{f(x)} =
  \sage{diff(f, x, 2)(x)}.
\]

Here's a plot of $f$ from $-1$ to $1$:

\sageplot{plot(f, -1, 1)}

\end{document}
```

But as you might suspect it didn't worked. I go to **tools**>**users** and select the **SAGE:SAGE** profile and all I got is this PDF
[image]

With this message,

> Error: Impossible to run the command: sage "Sage-example".sagetex.sage

[image]

Moreover, I can't figure out how to navigate in my SageMath console (not *Shell* or *Notebook*) till my working directory and run my `filename.sagetex.sage` with the command `sage`, seem more like a UNIX environment in wich I can not find any of my actual folders.
And when I try to run `sage filename.sagetex.sage` the windows prompt tell me it's an unrecognized comand.

Any idea in what could be the problem??

Thanks.

Comment: The easiest way to try `sagetex` is with a [free Cocalc account](https://cocalc.com/). To change directories, try `cd` with a path to the directory containing your file; eg, `cd '/home/MyDocuments'`.

Comment: Well ok, but I really would make it work on my machine. I started with ShareLatex, then I switched on my PC because for some assignement I couldn't plot all the graphs (it needed too much compiling time, for the free version) I needed. 
Now that I'm aware of this "issue" I'm a bit reluctant on going on a cloud based service .

Comment: As expected.....

> Free Trial (Day 4) – buy a license (starting at about $3/month) and apply it to this project.
> Otherwise, expect VERY bad performance (e.g., 10 times slower!) and you can't install packages, clone from GitHub, or download datasets.

So this sagetex example work perfectly, but I can't make the ```subfile``` package work properly. I have a cover I use for my weekly assignemts, and the I link my assignment with ```subfile```. I do have to submit a notebook at the end of my course, with all my weekly assignements, so I have to link all of them as they are already done.

Comment: Cocalc performance has dropped as late but for typical use, like your sample above, it shouldn't be a problem. I haven't worked with the `subfile` package but with a quick search on this site I found the post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312121/include-not-working-in-sagemath-latex) which indicates that the `subfiles` package is supported for SMC, now Cocalc. They even link to a working example on github. If you aren't able to get that to work, contact Cocalc help.